# SharePoint Online - Switch pages library back to modern view

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-document-library

Does anyone know how to switch the pages Library back to the Modern experience. I've read a few blogs that say go to the Library settings > Advanced > List Experience > New or Classic experience but this only works for document libraries. I've also tried clearing browser history.

Thanks

Comment: try clearing cache. You only cleared browsing history.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion but I've already tried that. For some reason the pages library doesn't have the List experience setting as document libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I hunted the cookie down, found out how to delete cookies in javascript and put it all in a script-webpart:

```
var delete_cookie = function(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; Path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};
delete_cookie('splnu');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for a bookmarklet based on @Robert's JavaScript:

```
javascript:(function(){ document.cookie = 'splnu=; Path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';location.reload(true);}());
```

To use, add a new bookmark in your browser's bookmark manager, copy and paste the code above as the address and name it something like "Return to Modern."

When you click the new bookmark, it will remove the cookie and reload the page in modern view.

## Reference

- [Beginner Geek: How to Use Bookmarklets on Any Device](https://www.howtogeek.com/189358/beginner-geek-how-to-use-bookmarklets-on-any-device/)
- [function as google chrome bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872679/function-as-google-chrome-bookmark)